# Modificar el tamaño de una celda (PdfPCell) para formato dentro de PdfPTable con ITextSharp en C#

Tags: c#, pdf, itextsharp

Saludos, tengo un problema al generar una tabla dentro de un archivo PDF utilizando ITextSharp en C#. El problema es que al intentar asignar el tamaño de la celda no lo respeta al momento de generar el PDF.

La idea es tener un documento con el siguiente formato:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  Document document = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);
            try
            {
                var fileName = $"File{DateTime.Now}.pdf";
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create));
                document.Open();
                var imagesCount  = imagesList.Count;
                var numberOfPages = imagesCount / 4 + 1;                   

                var imageIndex = 0;

                while (imageIndex < imagesCount)
                {
                    var table = new PdfPTable(2);
                    table.WidthPercentage = 100f;
                    //Filas
                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
                    {
                        var cells = new PdfPCell[2];
                        //Columnas
                        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        {
                            if (imagesCount > imageIndex)
                            {
                                var image = imagesList[imageIndex];

                                var cell = new PdfPCell();
                                cell.AddElement(image);
                                cell.FixedHeight = PageSize.LETTER.Height / 2;
                                cells[j] = cell;
                                imageIndex++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        var row = new PdfPRow(cells);
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                        if (investigation.Images.Count() <= imageIndex)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    document.Add(table);
                    document.NewPage();
                }                 

                document.Close();                   
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrias intentar asignando la propiedad

```
cell.Image.ScaleToFitHeight = true;
```

Si es que el problema se trata que la imagen no ocupa la celda

Tambien podrias definir un borde en la tabla para ver las dimensiones que estan tomando las celdas

[iTextSharp Image minimum Table cell height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589209/itextsharp-image-minimum-table-cell-height)

Comment: Tuttini sos grande

Answer (score 0):

[image: Alguien por favor que me ayude con esta tabla, quiero que la tabla tenga 15 Items fijos y que el tamaño de las celdas sea sea según el contenido que coloque en cada celda ademas de ello que cuando llegue a los 15 Items el cuadrado vaya aumentando, y si solamente tiene los 15 Items que el cuadrado este fijo... agradecería un aporte de como hacerlo por acá de mi código]

```
For I = 0 To 5

    lField = Trim(ColName(I) & "")
    'If I > 3 Then 

    celda = New pdf.PdfPCell(New Phrase(numformat(Trim(oFila(lField) & "")), fuenteDatos))
    ' Else
    celda = New pdf.PdfPCell(New Phrase(Trim(oFila(lField) & ""), fuenteDatos))
    ' End If

    'celda.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER
    'celda.Border = iTextSharp.text.Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER
    'celda.Border = Rectangle.RIGHT_BORDER

    'celda.Border = Rectangle.LEFT_BORDER
    'celda.Border = Rectangle.ALIGN_RIGHT

    'celda.Border = Rectangle.CCITTG3_2D 'solo lineas horizontales
    celda.Border = Rectangle.PARAGRAPH
    celda.Rowspan = 10
    celda.Colspan = 1

    celda.Padding = 3
    Select Case I
        Case 0 : celda.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        Case 1 : celda.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        Case 2 : celda.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT
        Case 3 : celda.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER
        Case Else : celda.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_RIGHT

    End Select

    celda.VerticalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_TOP
    TblDetalle.AddCell(celda)
Next

' xx = xx + 1
```

Next oFila